# Spritesheet creator/importer for unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I am currently developing a 2d game for android using Unity3d , but i am wondering if is there any free sprite sheet creator software that is compatible with unity3d without the extra code to be written , i've tried `texture packer` with there plugin for unity and it work great but this software is paid and i can not afford it right now ,
i also tried `Sprite Sheet Packer` but when i import the sprite sheet into unity and trim the sprites in the editor the animation does not work properly due to the fact that unity did not know the pivot point and the exact information of the sprite inside the created sprite sheet,
Does anyone know some useful free software that i can use or some unity plugin that can serve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I personally always used TexturePacker (then when I moved to Unity, NGUI does the work for me), so this is a recommendation from a friend:

http://renderhjs.net/shoebox/

A quick test showed that it made a PNG and accompanying XML file with the image data inside. Seems pretty simple.

Comment: when i extract the sprite sheet and get the xml file how can i tell unity to read from this xml file and not use it's default editor and slicing tool ? do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This question still actual in 2017. So this is my approach:

1) Get xml file with coordinates from your editor. I use DarkFunction sprite editor for fast and smart creation of coordinates. It's free and pretty clever to do lots of jobs automatically.

2) Install [this](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/36103) asset from asset store, it's free.

3) Tweak the TextureAtlasSlicer.cs file from the installed asset to correspond to your xml format. You have to do this only once.

That's it.